Limit sequence of regular function in $L_1$‘s unit sphere
Let $U$ denote the set of functions $f\in L_1([0,1]^2)$ such that $\int f=1$. For any $f\in U$, we say it is regular if $\int_{x_0\times [0,1]}f=\int_{[0,1]\times y_0}f=1$ for a.e. every $x_0, y_0\in [0,1]$. Let $U_0\subseteq U$ denote every regular functions in $U$. For any sequence ${f_i}$ in $U$, we say it weak-star convengent to $f_0\in U$ if for any continous function $h$ we have: $\int(f_i-f_0)h\to 0.$
Question: For any sequence ${f_i}$ in $U_0$, by Banach-Alaoglu we know that there exists its sub-sequence $f_{i_j}$ such that it weak-star convengent to $f'\in U$. Could we ensure that $f'\in U_0$ also holds?


You shoul add "a.e." to the definition of $U_0$ 2) If you want to apply Banach-Alaoglu, here the limit in general would be a Radon signed measure. Or do you assume that the limit of  $f_{i_j}$ is in L¹ ?


To rephrase Pietro's comment (2), $L^1$ is not the dual of any Banach space, so Banach-Alaoglu is a non-starter.

To rephrase the question in simple terms. Let's use two different intervals $I:=[a,b]$ and $J:=[c,d]$ for more clarity.
Let  a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of integrable functions on the rectangle $I\times J$ be given, such that for every continuous function $h$ on $I\times J$  one has  $\int_{I\times J}f_nh \to\int_{I\times J}f_0h $. Assuming that for every $n\ge1$ $$\int_I f_n(x,y_0)dy=\int_J f_n(x_0,y)dx=1\quad \text{for a.e. } x_0\in I, \text{  a.e. } y_0\in J$$
can one deduce that the same holds for $n=0$ too? Yes: for every $u\in C^0(I)$ one has by Fubini
$$0=\int_I\Big(\int_J \big(f_n(x,y)-1\big)dy\Big)u(x)dx=\int_{I\times J }\big(f_n(x,y)-1\big)u(x)d(x,y)$$
therefore taking the limit on the RHS, the same holds for $n=0$ by the assumption, and  then  $I\ni x\mapsto \int_J \big(f_0(x,y)-1\big)dy$ (which is an integrable function  by Fubini) vanishes for a.e. $x\in I$ (this is the "Fundamental lemma of the Calculus of Variations"). Thus, $\int_Jf_0(x,y) dy=1$ a.e. Analogously $\int_I f_0(x,y) dx=1$ a.e.
$$*$$
rmk For a Functional Analysis perspective, the relevant duality is rather $L^1(I\times J)^*=L^\infty(I\times J)$. Translate $U_0$ by  the constant function $1\in L^1(I\times J)$, so $V_0:=U_0-1$ is the linear subspace $$\{f\in L^1(I\times J): \int_If(x,\cdot)dx=\int_Jf(\cdot,y)dy=0\}$$
Then $V_0$ is the pre-annihilator of the subspace
$L^\infty(I)+L^\infty(J)\subset L^\infty(I\times J)$, that is  $$\{h : h(x,y)=u(x)+v(y), \exists u\in L^1(I), \exists v\in L^1(J)\}.$$
